# Citing inside a table

Tags: tables, citing

I can't make \autocite work inside tables. It produces af footnote mark (number) inside the table, but it doesn't produce any footnote at the bottom of the page.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        xxx & xxx \autocite{LKH} \\ \hline
        xxx & xxx \\ \hline
        xxx & xxx \autocite{LKH} \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[hidelinks,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=numeric,backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{array}

\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{4em}{2em}

\bibliography{references}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Jeppe Kjærsgaard}
\chead{Finansøkonom}
\rhead{CPH Business}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.59999pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1cm}
\newcommand{\colorrow}{\rowcolor[HTML]{FACB7F}}

\newcommand{\charactercount}[1]{
\immediate\write18{
    expr `texcount -1 -sum -merge #1.tex` + `texcount -1 -sum -merge -char #1.tex` - 1 
    > chars.txt
}\input{chars.txt}}
```

I have control of my reference list, so theres no problem there. The only problem is that theres a number inside the table at the citation, but no footnote with the reference.

I have a few references before the table, so the reference numbers would be 14 and 15, which is shown inside the table, but unfortunately not in the bottom.

I am writing in overleaf.

Thanks in regards!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try to insert `\footnotemark` inside the table and `\footnotetext{...}` inside? Other than that, you might load the `tablefootnote` package and use the eponymous command.

Comment: Hi Bernard! Thanks a lot! 
I have tried the footnotemark, but same problem occurs! 
How do i use the tablefootnote package? If i just loads the package, nothing changes. And I'm not quite sure how to use the eponymous command, it you'd like to elaborate please.

Comment: Actually, the footnotemark WOULD work, if I didn't have two references in the table, as I could just place the footnotetext outside the table. But it only considers the latest footnotemark when entering a footnotetext.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this behaviour. Maybe it would work with  the package I mentioned?